# Venv activate does not change to new pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, python-venv

On Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with Python 3.8 I was trying to create a venv for a project to install certain versions of dependencies. I used the usual venv command `python3 -m venv venv` to create a venv in the dir `venv`, and `source venv/bin/activate` to activate it. However after some time I found out it didn't work as expected.

Apparently the python3 path was switched successfully but the pip didn't.

I used `which python3`, `which pip` and `which python3 -m pip` to check.
Same for `pip3` and `pip3.8`. While python shows the one inside the venv dir, pip does not.

I noticed that pip is also missing from the `/venv/bin/` dir, but I don't know why. On my other machine pip is included in the `/venv/bin/` dir and is used after activate as I expect it to.

I didn't find a solution on similar questions on stackoverflow, hence I'm opening this one.

I tried to locate `pip.conf` files as suggested in one older question on here but had none present.
I also made sure that `venv/pyvenv.cfg` contains `include-system-site-packages = false`.

EDIT: I also tried running `python -m ensurepip` with the venv activated but it states `Requirement already satisfied` and shows the path for the outside pip.

Comment: Are you sure you did just `python3 -m venv venv` and not with `--without-pip` flag? Because no pip in venv/bin would suggest the `--without-pip` version.  Could you try to do `python -m pip` when your venv is activated? If it says `No module named pip`, then it means venv has no pip at all. If it works, it means the pip is there but for some reason scripts for pip weren't created for this venv. Maybe also compare (venv not active in system) `python3 -m pip --version` and `pip --version`

Comment: Yes I am sure. `python -m pip list` e.g. works in the activated venv but uses the pip outside venv which is my problem.
The two versions commands you suggested show the same pip version which is the one outside of the pip.

So yes, I guess pip is not created in the venv but I am not sure why or how to fix this.

Comment: try tyoing `hash -r` in your shell to see if your shell just didn't update everything

Comment: Sometimes for people with similar issues it turned out there was some `alias` causing trouble. -- If `python` points to the one in the virtual environment, then I do not see how `python -m pip` could point to a *pip* outside the virtual environment, that seems impossible to me (unless there is something like `include-system-site-packages` of course). -- Is there a wheel of *pip* available for *ensurepip*? Did it use to work before? How was this Python installed?

Comment: @sinoroc good point, I checked `alias` but there weren't any regarding python or pip. Yes I cannot see how this is not working either. `include-system-site-packages` is set to `false`.
For the other questions, I don't know as this occurs on a remote machine I did not set up. However python and python-venv etc. are listed in `apt list --installed` so they are probably managed via apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the reason it didn't work were some environment variables. I still want to put it here, if anyone else seems stuck on a similar issue and cannot find another working solution.

Make sure to check all set environment variables e.g. by running `printenv`.

For me specifically I had to `unset` every environment variable which had PYTHON in it's name.